# Merge two arrays based on Foreign Keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a search function, which looks up two models `A` and `B`. The results are `@a` and `@b`. Both consist of `manufacturer_id` and `model_id`:

```
@a = [
  #<A id: 6, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 6, front: 30, side: 39, rear: 19, roof: 0, created_at: "2016-12-17 23:34:58", updated_at: "2016-12-17 23:34:58">,
  #<A id: 10, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 10, front: 30, side: 39, rear: 19, roof: 0, created_at: "2016-12-17 23:34:58", updated_at: "2016-12-17 23:34:58">
]
@b = [
  #<B id: 167, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 6, FL_1: 30, FL_2: 24, FR_1: 30, FR_2: 24, FC_1: 0, FC_2: 0, RL_1: 22, RL_2: 24, RR_1: 22, RR_2: 24, RC_1: 20, RC_2: 11, third_1: 0, third_2: 0, forth_1: 0, forth_2: 0, boot_1: 0, boot_2: 0, total: 60, created_at: "2016-12-17 23:35:10", updated_at: "2016-12-17 23:35:10">,
  #<B id: 175, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 10, FL_1: 28, FL_2: 22, FR_1: 28, FR_2: 22, FC_1: 0, FC_2: 0, RL_1: 26, RL_2: 22, RR_1: 26, RR_2: 22, RC_1: 12, RC_2: 18, third_1: 0, third_2: 0, forth_1: 0, forth_2: 0, boot_1: 0, boot_2: 0, total: 44, created_at: "2016-12-17 23:35:10", updated_at: "2016-12-17 23:35:10">
]
```

I am trying to merge the two arrays based on their `manufacturer_id` and `model_id`. The expected result is:

```
@output = [#<A id: 6, B id: 167, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 6>], #<A id: 10, B id: 175, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 10>]
```

In my view, my result should still be able to refer to `manufacturer` and `model` models and obtain the specific parameter.

```
<% @output.each do |r| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= r.manufacturer.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to r.model.name, edit_model_path(r) %></td>
    <td colspan=2>
        <%= link_to "View", a_path(r), class: "button btn btn-success btn-xs" %> 
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_b_path(r), class: "button btn btn-warning btn-xs" %>
    </td>
    <td colspan=2>
        <%= link_to "View", b_path(r), class: "button btn btn-success btn-xs" %> 
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_b_path(r), class: "button btn btn-warning btn-xs" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I found out that I can join both of them using `id`. However, I have no clue how to join them based on their common/foreign key `id`.

I tried this, but it did not do the job:

```
outputs = (@a+@b).group_by{|h| h[:manufacturer_id]}.map{|k,v| v.reduce(:merge)}
```

Please guide me.

Comment: Do you have a correct example for a and b, and what your output should be? Ruby Arrays are between `[]`. Also, please don't use variable or attribute names, but concrete example with Ruby objects (1, "model_x", ...)

Comment: @EricDuminil I added the actual example based on your suggestion. The reason why I wanted to put it that way so that people can see it easily. Thanks!

Comment: a is an Array of `A` objects, b is an Array of `B` objects, and you want to group a and b by `manufacturer_id` and `model_id`?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` models? Are `a` and `b` arrays of objects from the same model?

Comment: `A` and `B` are models, each of them consists of foreign keys: `manufacturer_id` and `model_id`. When I search by their `manufacturer and model name`, they will return two arrays (different model), `a` and `b` (each contains different information for the `manufacturer` and `model`). My main goal is to merge two of the array by obtaining their `a.id` and `b.id` so I can redirect to the correct path (to view), and the `manufacturer_id` and `model_id` have to be retained in the array, so I can reference the `manufacturer` and `model` name in my view. I hope this my explanation is clear for you :)

Comment: When you provide an example (usually a good thing), please do the following: 1). ensure the inputs are valid Ruby objects (e.g., no `...`); 2) make the example as brief as possible while still making the point (here, three key-value pairs); 3) assist readers who wish to run code with your example by avoiding irrelevant complications (here avoid date or time values); 4) show the expected result for the given example; and 5) assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `a = [#<a id: 6,...`) so that readers can refer to those variables without having to define them.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I edited my question by putting all parameters in the array. The reason why I refused to put the complete array was because it might be too long as it contains too many attributes.

Comment: That's better, Melvin. My point #2 was to reduce the number of keys to the minimum. I suggested three (`manufacture_id, :model_id` and one other) as additional key-values appear to be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Your expected array `@output` is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [set intersection](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-26) to find the objects with common ids.

Update : set union is now used, to output every id combination.

```
@a = [
  { id: 6, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 6 },
  { id: 10, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 10 },
  { id: 111, manufacturer_id: 3, model_id: 4 }
]

@b = [
  { id: 167, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 6 },
  { id: 175, manufacturer_id: 1, model_id: 10 },
  { id: 176, manufacturer_id: 2, model_id: 3 }
]

def group_by_ids(array)
  array.group_by { |h| h.values_at(:manufacturer_id, :model_id) }
end

a_by_ids = group_by_ids(@a)
b_by_ids = group_by_ids(@b)

common_keys = a_by_ids.keys & b_by_ids.keys
all_keys    = a_by_ids.keys | b_by_ids.keys

result = all_keys.map do |ids|
  a_objects = a_by_ids[ids]
  b_objects = b_by_ids[ids]
  a_object  = a_objects && a_objects.first
  b_object  = b_objects && b_objects.first
  [*ids, a_object, b_object]
end
```

It outputs :

```
[[1,
  6,
  {:id=>6, :manufacturer_id=>1, :model_id=>6},
  {:id=>167, :manufacturer_id=>1, :model_id=>6}],
 [1,
  10,
  {:id=>10, :manufacturer_id=>1, :model_id=>10},
  {:id=>175, :manufacturer_id=>1, :model_id=>10}],
 [3, 4, {:id=>111, :manufacturer_id=>3, :model_id=>4}, nil],
 [2, 3, nil, {:id=>176, :manufacturer_id=>2, :model_id=>3}]]
```

So you get an array of arrays, where each sub-array looks like :

```
[manufacturer_id, model_id, a_object, b_object]
```

You might need to adapt your views a bit, but you should have enough information in each array.

Comment: I received an error, `undefined method 'group_by' for nil:NilClass` at this `array.group_by{|h| [h[:manufacturer_id], h[:model_id]]}` line.

Comment: It means either `@a` or `@b` isn't defined.

Comment: For those results that do not match, is it possible to have `a_object` or `b_object` in the array to be 0 if any of them does not exist? Eg. `[manufacturer_id, model_id, a_object, 0]`, since b_object does not exists.

Comment: Sure. Which ruby version do you use?

Comment: Ruby 2.2.3 (Rails 5.0.01, just want to exceed the minimum character in the comment)

Comment: Here you go. `a` or `b` objects are now allowed to be `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach.

```
[@a, @b].flatten.group_by do |row|
  row.values_at(:manufacturer_id, :model_id)
end.reduce([]) do |output, ((manufacturer_id, model_id), data)|
  output << data.reduce({}) { |memo, x| memo.merge(x) }
end
```

If you need to do any sort of renaming to keep hash values from colliding, you can modify the block passed to `data.reduce` to do a more nuanced `merge`.

Comment: Both of the approaches you provided gave me an error, `undefined method 'values_at' for nil:NilClass``. I looked at the API and have no clue why that happens

Comment: Nice use of double reduce :). If I understand your code correctly, you expect elements of `@a` and `@b` arrays to respond to `merge`, which might not be the case here.